# SSH console file management

Tags: ssh, console

Do you know how to do file transfers via ssh. It's like you open two instances of the project and you transfer file from that remote instance to your instance.

I was able to do this before via Putty but I completely forgot the keys I press to get this thing to work.

It is like Midnight Commander where you have a cursor and two panels. Please if you know the keys to press to make it appear on my console....THAT'D BE AWESOME! The image below is how it also look like when I did it on Putty...a very long time ago.
[image]

I can't really remember the keys I press.

Comment: actually this _is_ a midnight commander. putty is just an ssh client

Comment: Yes this is the midnight commander. I pressed something in Putty and it shows me two panels also...just like midnight commander. I was able to copy and transfer files from one panel to another. GAWD I should've written it down! I CANNOT REMEMBER! AAAHHHH!

Comment: Actually you can do these panels thing in any console that has cursor ability. I tried the jEdit sshConsole but it has no cursor ability, so I used Putty instead. It's annoying when you forget what you did! GAWD!

Comment: in this case it was definitely winscp

Comment: When I can remember, I'll post it here...so I won't forget! Ever...again :L

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just a part of the answer.

Personnally i'm using SCP.

```
scp localfile user@server:destfile
```

Moreover, tools like gftp do it really well (when you choose the protocol ssh into the combobox at the right).

Comment: No that's not it...not ringing any bell. But I appreciate your input :D Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

For putty you have to open a windows command line (cmd)

Then type:

> pscp source_file_name
>   userid@server_name:/path/destination_file_name

I think you'll find using winSCP is much easier.  SSH doesn't support file transfer within the shell itself.  You have to use the tool scp (pscp = putty scp).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to make file transfers with `mc` - just click on the panel you wish(`Left` or `Right` in the menu bar), select `Shell link` and write the connection details in the next window.

If you are asking about ssh generally - use `scp` as others have suggested.